# It doesn't work using DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a animation using DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames to turn a rectangle. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
        rect.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        ScaleTransform myScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myScaleTransform);

        rect.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;

        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        EasingDoubleKeyFrame myEasingDoubleKeyFrame = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = -1;
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 1;
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction = new CubicEase()
        {
            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
        };

        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, rect);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX"));

        Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
        myStoryboard.Begin();
```

The XAML file is:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect"  Width="200" Height="100"  Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Nothing happens ? Is there an exception ? What does it say ?

Comment: I solved the problem with the help of Clemens. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular DoubleAnimation. Then you don't need more code than this:

```
var transform = new ScaleTransform();
var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = -1,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
};

rect.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
rect.RenderTransform = transform;

transform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animation);
```

---

You might also set the `RenderTransform` and `RenderTransformOrigin` properties in XAML:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Black"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Then your code reduces to this:

```
rect.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = -1,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
        EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
    });
```

Comment: I am wondering why my code doesn't work. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Your code didn't work because you added only one key frame to `myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames`. That one frame had a `Value` of `1`, which is the current property value anyway, so no animation takes place.

Comment: Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX")); Is the code wrong? When I debug, exception throws from this code.

Comment: The code isn't wrong in your example above. When you add another key frame, it will run.